# Testing Coinbase API with Postman : pagination gives me error

Tags: api, authentication, pagination, coinbase-api

I am testing the Coinbase API endpoints with Postman and the challenge is when I need to paginate

In order to setup Postman, I have followed the guide available [here](https://www.stefanbruhns.tech/authenticated-calls-to-coinbase-api-with-postman/) and in summary:

1. added variables

   - coinbase-api-base
   - coinbase-api-key
   - coinbase-api-secret
   - coinbase-api-timestamp
   - coinbase-api-signature
2. Added pre-request script in order to generate the request signature

> ```
> // 1. Import crypto-js library
>
> var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
>
> // 2. Create the JSON request object var req = { timestamp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000), // seconds since Unix epoch method:
> pm.request.method, path: pm.request.url.getPath(), body: '', // empty
> for GET requests message: undefined, secret:
> pm.collectionVariables.get("coinbase-api-secret"), // read value from
> collection variable hmac: undefined, signature: undefined, };
>
> // 3. Create the message to be signed req.message = req.timestamp + req.method + req.path + req.body;
>
> // 4. Create HMAC using message and API secret req.hmac = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(req.message, req.secret);
>
> // 5. Obtain signature by converting HMAC to hexadecimal String req.signature = req.hmac.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
>
> // 6. Log the request console.info("request: ", req);
>
> // 7. Set Postman request's authentication headers for Coinbase REST API call pm.collectionVariables.set("coinbase-api-timestamp",
> req.timestamp); pm.collectionVariables.set("coinbase-api-signature",
> req.signature);
> ```

all worked well for a simple request such as:

> GET {{coinbase-api-base}}/v2/accounts

then, if I add in the body request parameter (as explained [here](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#pagination)):

> limit=50

to change the default pagination, I get an authentication error....

> "errors": [
> {     "id": "authentication_error",
> "message": "invalid signature"
> }

questions:

how can I fix it?

how the body of the request can play with the request signature...

any help suggestion is much appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Edit: the below being said, I'm not sure the base accounts API supports paging I could be wrong though, the CB docs are inconsistent to say the least. It does seem that the account history (ledger) and holds do though.

https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/exchange/reference/exchangerestapi_getaccounts

get accounts function in Node.js API doesn't give an args param where the ledger does (see below):

```
getAccounts(callback) {
  return this.get(['accounts'], callback);
}
```

Documentation for an api that does support paging, notice it gives you a query param section not available in the accounts documentation:

https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/exchange/reference/exchangerestapi_getaccountledger

Looking at the node api, you still need to add the query string params to the body in order to sign:

calling function:

```
return this.get(
  ['accounts', accountID, 'ledger'],
  { qs: args },
  callback
);
```

signing function:

```
let body = '';
if (options.body) {
body = JSON.stringify(options.body);
} else if (options.qs && Object.keys(options.qs).length !== 0) {
    body = '?' + querystring.stringify(options.qs);
}
const what = timestamp + method.toUpperCase() + path + body;
const key = Buffer.from(auth.secret, 'base64');
const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', key);
const signature = hmac.update(what).digest('base64');
return {
  key: auth.key,
  signature: signature,
  timestamp: timestamp,
  passphrase: auth.passphrase,
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't add the limit to the body of the request, GET requests never includes any body.

You should add it as a query string parameter like (this is just an example):

```
GET {{coinbase-api-base}}/v2/accounts?limit=50
```

Comment: Thank you. I probably asked it wrong ;) I have not put in request body... I added the limit in the url and suddenly it seems that my signature generated with the pre request script is not valid... but without the parameters in url, it works fine...